# How to find a real similar matrix to a complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a real similar matrix to the following matrix:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & i & -i \\
        0 & 1-i & \phantom-i \\
        0 & 0 & 1+i \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the determinant is real, so why not. Find some real matrix with the same eigenvalues (a simple rotation would do), then the eigenvectors of both, then change basis to bring one to the other.

In short, if your matrix is $A$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-1\\0&0&1\\0&i&1\end{pmatrix}$, then $B^{-1}AB=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&-1&1\end{pmatrix}$